# JQuery/Javascript, how do I grab the data-url through multiple 'same' div's?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div id="siteTable">  
    <div class="thing id12" data-url="www.aaax.com"</div>
    <div class="thing id23" data-url="www.bcbc.com"</div>
    <div class="thing id34" data-url="www.eeed.com"</div>
    <div class="thing id45" data-url="www.djhn.com"</div>
     .
     .
     .
     .
    <div class="thing id92295" data-url="www.zzzzhn.com"</div>
</div>
```

How would I go about getting the data-url of each of the div thing classes under siteTable?

Comment: Do you want to just put them all in an array or what are you looking to do? What have you tried? An easy place to start would be `$('.thing').each(function() { var $this = $(this); var url = $this.attr('data-url')})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get all the elements which have the attribute using [has attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) and iterate over them using [`each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) method.

```js
$('#siteTable div[data-url]').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).data('url'))
  // or
  // console.log(this.dataset.url)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="siteTable">
  <div class="thing id12" data-url="www.aaax.com"></div>
  <div class="thing id23" data-url="www.bcbc.com"></div>
  <div class="thing id34" data-url="www.eeed.com"></div>
  <div class="thing id45" data-url="www.djhn.com"></div>
  . . . .
  <div class="thing id92295" data-url="www.zzzzhn.com"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get array of url's using `map()` and `get()` methods.

```js
var urls = $('#siteTable > div.thing').map(function() {
  return $(this).data('url')
}).get()

console.log(urls)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="siteTable">
  <div class="thing id12" data-url="www.aaax.com"></div>
  <div class="thing id23" data-url="www.bcbc.com"></div>
  <div class="thing id34" data-url="www.eeed.com"></div>
  <div class="thing id45" data-url="www.djhn.com"></div>
  <div class="thing id92295" data-url="www.zzzzhn.com"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

ES6 one-liner:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#siteTable > .thing')).map(div => div.getAttribute('data-url'))
```

```js
var urls = 
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#siteTable > .thing')).map(div => div.getAttribute('data-url'))
console.log(urls)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="siteTable">
  <div class="thing id12" data-url="www.aaax.com"></div>
  <div class="thing id23" data-url="www.bcbc.com"></div>
  <div class="thing id34" data-url="www.eeed.com"></div>
  <div class="thing id45" data-url="www.djhn.com"></div>
  <div class="thing id92295" data-url="www.zzzzhn.com"></div>
</div>
```

jQuery one-liner:

```
$('#siteTable > .thing').map(function() {return $(this).attr('data-url')}).get()
```

```js
var urls = 
$('#siteTable > .thing').map(function() {return $(this).attr('data-url')}).get()
console.log(urls)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="siteTable">
  <div class="thing id12" data-url="www.aaax.com"></div>
  <div class="thing id23" data-url="www.bcbc.com"></div>
  <div class="thing id34" data-url="www.eeed.com"></div>
  <div class="thing id45" data-url="www.djhn.com"></div>
  <div class="thing id92295" data-url="www.zzzzhn.com"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#siteTable .thing").each(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr("data-url");
});
```

Or in jQuery 1.4.3 or later:

```
$("#siteTable .thing").each(function() {
    console.log($(this).data("url");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the childnodes of the div with id siteTable and then for each child get the `data-url` attribute.